# I am not sure how to request Django rest-framework Social Oauth2

Tags: django, reactjs, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add Google & Facebook social auth to my DRF api. I followed steps from [readme](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2), I read the docs but I don't know how to request my api  from my react app - docs shows this example for facebook login:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_scret>&backend=facebook&token=<facebook_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token`
```

And here my problem comes - I don't understand what is "client_secret" in curl request? Should it be the same as `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET` in settings (that is copied from facebook developers site)?

Answer (score 2):

According to their documentation:

`<client_id> and <client_secret> are the keys generated automatically that you can find in the model Application you created.`